# Vue - deep copy with vuex doesn't work in vuejs

Tags: vue.js

there
when I use Vue + Vuex in my project, I found an issue,
my code:

store:

```
const state = {
  createInfo: {
    id: 0,
    // group_id: rootState.home.currentGroup,
    content: '',
    image_info: [],
    video_info: [],
    lat: '',
    lng: '',
    type: 1
  },
  list: [],
  canLoad: true 
}
```

function of mutations:

```
setPublishInfoImages(state, {key, value}) {
    if (key === 'push') {
      state.createInfo.image_info.push(value)
    } else {
      state.createInfo.image_info.splice(key, 1)
    }
  },
```

on page
first way:

```
let sourceTopic = Object.assign({}, {
        image_info: [],
        video_info: [],
        content: '',
        type: 1
      }, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.$store.getters['topic/signTopic'](topic))))
```

second way:

```
let sourceTopic = Object.assign({}, {
        image_info: [],
        video_info: [],
        content: '',
        type: 1
      }, Object.assign({}, this.$store.getters['topic/signTopic'](topic))
```

I want deep copy a source Object which in state's list array from state use getter

```
const getters = {
  /** get sign topic */
  signTopic: (state) => (id) => {
    return state.list.data.find((topic) => topic.id === id) || {}
  }
}
```

yes, I got the Object from state,

but when I update the state (uploadimage, and push image-url into state),
first way, there is only one image-url in source images array forever,

second way, when I cannel editing source object, uploaded image-urls will be stored in source object

how can i resolve this issue?

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to push image-URL into the state and do not change the source object,  In fact, the object must be changed after posting data to  server-side, but, if I Cancel editing before posting data to server-side, the source Object  can not be changed

Comment: I've resolved this issue, I get the source object in the wrong lifecycle method, sorry